# how to do heroku with python (or ruby) and nodejs?

Tags: python, angularjs, django, node.js, heroku

I have an obstacle with Heroku that I haven't figured out the best way to solve, but maybe I'm missing something.

Before I explain more, let me first say that I am familiar with Heroku's:

```
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-multi.git
```

And indeed I have a .buildpacks file that looks like:

```
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs.git
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python.git
```

The **TL;DR** of my question is, how can I tell heroku that the base directory of my nodejs app is not in the root directory?

How can I tell Heroku to apply the nodejs buildpack starting at /dir1/dir2/ui of my app and use that directory as the base directory? But for python use /dir1 as the base directory?

The general idea is that I'll be running some sort of Python WSGI server (whether it be Flask or Django...or even, say, Ruby on Rails). But I'll be building my front-end content (scss files, JS files, HTML files) using a suite of node packages.

More than once I've started a project using some sort of Python starter/seed project that will generate a simple skeleton server with routes and a trivial Angular front-end.

Then I'll quickly using something like yeoman to generate a richer and more mature front-end that uses node and gulp to do all sorts of handy front-end magic.

Then I'll merge the yeoman UI project structure into my python project to get a full project using best practices from both Python and node/npm/gulp/bower/Angular.

After merging I'll generally have a project structure that looks like (some stuff omitted for brevity):

```
.buildpacks
Procfile
env/        # python virtual environment (not actually checked in to git)
heroku.sh
myproject_dir
    models/
    views/
    ui/
        # python templates (eg: *.jinja.html files). i'll predominantly
        # be using angular and partials, but I don't totally want to 
        # give up all server-side templates. SPAs, in reality are not
        # usually truly one single-page, but maybe 3 or 4 very rich
        # pages
        templates/
            index.jinja.html  # my main html file
        # static/ is where the yeoman project really merges in to 
        # the python project
        static/
            assets/
               images/
                   foo.jpg
            styles/
               app.css
            partials/
               app/
                   app.html
            src/
               app/
                   app.js
            test/
                test1.js
         # gulpfile.js and package.json live in the ui directory (not
         # in the static directory), because I actually do want gulp to
         # do some processing on my jinja server-side template files
         gulpfile.js
         package.json
         bower.json
         node_modules/
         bower_components/
manage.py   # python top-level for managing script for various things
requirements.txt    # python package dependencies
runtime.txt
```

And now we've arrived at my problem with heroku.

I have 2 build environments, python and node/gulp. But I want to tell heroku that my node environment starts in the ui/ directory.

But I haven't figured out how to do this. Is this achievable?

I should note, this heroku issue is very related: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs/issues/230

It currently looks like if I were to have my python manage.py script to kick off a gulp build it would fail to find node and npm. It's possible I could have my manage.py script actually go fetch and install node/npm on its own, but this seems crazy.

Answer (score 0):

Using the setup you describe on heroku sounds complicated for the buildpack system, and would probably involve forking the standard heroku packs and tweaking their bash scripts.  When I did this with R + Python integration, it wasn't fun, but you can iteratively attempt with [Vagrant](https://atlas.hashicorp.com/lazygray/boxes/heroku-cedar-14).

You might find it easier to work with Heroku's [Docker support](https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2015/5/5/introducing_heroku_docker_release_build_deploy_heroku_apps_with_docker).  This gives you control of how your build environment works at every level, and personally fits my brain better.  It will still involve iterative tweaking to get the build Just Right.

Comment: Thanks!. Very helpful. I hadn't thought about Vagrant, just didn't realize they have an image out there and debugging my buildpack has been a real slog. For now I've just combined heroku's python and nodejs buildpacks into one, having nodejs run after python is in place. Vagrant will help.

Docker is also very interesting. I've never used it, but have heard tons about it. Indeed Docker is likely the way of the future for Heroku. Even though I've never used it I think I'd much prefer using a Dockerfile over a buildpack file. So much is undocumented about buildpack files and the env they run in.